# Error on testing method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

My working method, which need to be tested:

```
using TCatSysManagerLib; // for TcSysManager
public static int ProcessPositionBias(TcSysManager tcsm)
{
    // method body here
    return 0;
}
```

Now in Test Unit I tried to simulate TcSysManager, because it works with hardware, which is not available during tests and I can't even use it:

```
namespace TestClient
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTestClient
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestVersion()
        {
            Mock<TcSysManager> tcsm = new Mock<TcSysManager>();
        
            int r = ClientProgram.ProcessPositionBias(tcsm.Object); // errors here
        
        }
    }

    public TcSysManager
    {
        // I promise to implement some methods which I use in my app
    }
}
```

Basically compiler complains about 3 things:

> Error 1   The type 'TCatSysManagerLib.TcSysManager' is defined in an
> assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
> 'Interop.TCatSysManagerLib, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> Error 2   The best overloaded method match for
> 'Client.ClientProgram.ProcessPositionBias(TCatSysManagerLib.TcSysManager)'
> has some invalid
> arguments
>
> Error 3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TestClient.TcSysManager' to
> 'TCatSysManagerLib.TcSysManager'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: *"You must add a reference to assembly 'Interop.TCatSysManagerLib, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."* ?

Comment: I can't do that for Unit Testing, because the library is available only on "special computers".

Comment: Your only real option as far as I can tell would be to create a mock library that has the same namespace's and version as the 'special library' and reference it for your local testing, assuming it isn't signed or anything. Otherwise I don't see how anything could even build.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what's wrong. You can't just give a type the same name, you need the exact same type that the method you're calling requires.

An alternative could be to introduce an interface to the `TcSysManager`, declared in a separate assembly, and make the type of the method parameter of that interface.

Comment: Looks like the only way to declare interface in application itself.

Comment: Both the `Interop.TCatSysManagerLib` and the unit test project must reference the assembly that the interface is declared in.

Comment: I created an adapter class in my app, where the TCatSysManagerLib   is referenced and at the same time unit test project referencing app. Looks like the error is gone. I will try to create stub in test project.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Of course that is also an option, as long as you don't publicly expose the `TCatSysManagerLib` types from that wrapper. `ProcessPositionBias()` must then use your adapter class.